# Remove identical row from the data frame-Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to remove identical row that matches between two data frames . how ever, what ever method I am trying the identical rows in same data frame also gets dropped. But i want to retain the identical rows from same data frame and drop the ones which only matches with other data frame.

```
Dataframe 1:

 ID             PID         PDate      Amount
AAAAAA          NN11        20210525    386
BBBBBB          A12         20210525    3300
BBBBBB          A12         20210525    3300
CCCCCC          B11         20210625    1000

Dataframe 2:

 ID             PID         PDate      Amount
AAAAAA          NN11        20210525    386



Expected output:
 ID             PID         PDate      Amount
BBBBBB          A12         20210525    3300
BBBBBB          A12         20210525    3300
CCCCCC          B11         20210625    1000
```

I tried concatenating and drop duplicates, merge , reseting index. All these drops off ID BBBBBB as well because the rows with this ID are identical. I want to retain them .

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You could find the indices of the intersection of those dataframes with the one you want to compare to, and drop those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge your two dataframes by union of the keys. Use `indicator=True` parameter to keep the information on the source of each row. If the value is `both` drop the row.

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, how="outer", indicator=True) \
      .query("_merge != 'both'") \
      .drop(columns="_merge")

       ID  PID     PDate  Amount
1  BBBBBB  A12  20210525    3300
2  BBBBBB  A12  20210525    3300
3  CCCCCC  B11  20210625    1000
```

Comment: this worked for me. i was trying left outer join, outer but did not use query.  thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Try [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

```
df1[~df1.isin(df2).all(1)]
```

**Output**

```
    ID      PID PDate       Amount
1   BBBBBB  A12 20210525    3300
2   BBBBBB  A12 20210525    3300
3   CCCCCC  B11 20210625    1000
```

Comment: More  Elegant solution

Comment: this solution did not work for me :-(. thank you very much for your reply